# max function in sql

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table :

```
ID | time
1 | 124124244
2 | 211313112
3 | 131334334
```

I want to get row of `max(time)`.
I tried like this:

```
select ID,max(time) from T;
```

Although it gave correct max(time), but ID given was always 1. I can't get that whole row.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE `time` = (SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM T)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.ID, t.time from T
inner join (select MAX(time) maxTime FROM T) a
 ON a.maxTime = t.time;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e48a/5), with xdazz's answer also (both are working)

Answer (score 2):

If there are no two rows with same `time` or if you want one of them and don't care for the others, you can use this:

```
SELECT    id, time
FROM      T
ORDER BY  time DESC
    LIMIT 1 ;
```

If there are more than one rows with same `time`, @Raphael's answer will return all of them.

Answer (score 1):

`select id from tbl where time = 
(select max(time) from tbl)`

check this fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77acd/3